# How can I get all filename in different directories?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, os.path

Lets say the directories hierarchy looks like this:

```
          A(root)
          |
B---------C--------D
|         |        |
fileB.h  fileC.png  fileD.py
         fileC1.jpg
          E
          |
         fileE.py
```

How can I access all the doc? Or just get the path. Is there a way to iterlate all?

What I do:

```
path = sys.path[0]
for filename_dir in os.listdir(path):
     filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename_dir)
     if ext == '.h':
         #do something
     elif ext == '.png'
         #do something
     .....
```

But as I know `listdir` can only access the directory where my program's py file located.

Comment: Help on built-in function listdir in module posix:                                                                   
`listdir(...)                                  
    listdir(path) -> list_of_strings
    Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory.` <-- it takes an argument where you can give it the path.

Comment: btw [`listdir` doesn't really care about where your .py file is located](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).  The reason why you're getting only the files contained in the same directory as your .py file is because you're sending as argument [`sys.path[0]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: Thanks all comments and answers. So much links and info I had to learn. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives only the dirs and files under a directory, but not recursively:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print filename
```

If you want to list absolute paths:

```
import os

def listdir_fullpath(d):
    return [os.path.join(d, f) for f in os.listdir(d)]
```

If you want resursive search, this gives you an iterator that returns 3-tuples including the parent directory, list of directories, and list of files at each iteration:

```
for i,j,k in os.walk('.'):
    print i, j, k
```

For example:

```
    import os

    path = sys.path[0]

    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            print "FOUND DIRECTORY: ", os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        for filename in filenames:
            print "FOUND FILE: ", os.path.join(dirname, filename)
```